# Abrupt behaviour of mongodb in a conditional query

Tags: mongodb, mlab

My collection `steplist` has documents like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55d21e12dc00c4a4eb57e78d"
    },
    "start_lat": "22.788186",
    "start_lng": "86.159255",
    "end_lat": "22.8420794",
    "end_lng": "86.05532659999994"
}
```

When I try to query for documents which have `"start_lat"` less than value "14" using `db.steplist.find({start_lat: {$lte:"14"}})`, it returns documents as follows:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d21e2adc00c4a4eb57e862"),
    "start_lat" : "13.615239",
    "start_lng" : "79.5065763",
    "end_lat" : "13.3591181",
    "end_lng" : "79.08415630000002",
}
....
...
..
.
```

But when i try to search for documents which have less than value "9" using `db.steplist.find({start_lat: {$lte:"9"}})`, it returns documents as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d21e14dc00c4a4eb57e79e"),
    "start_lat" : "27.2241643",
    "start_lng" : "78.11668220000001",
    "end_lat" : "28.4484536",
    "end_lng" : "77.49778100000003"
}
```

Why am I getting wrong documents in this case?

Note:

1. There are documents with "start_lat" ranging from value 7 to 35 in the collection.
2. Also, When I search `db.steplist.find({start_lat: {$lte:"10"}})`, no documents are returned.
3. MongoDb is hosted on MongoLab

Comment: changed data type `start_lat,start_lng,end_lat,end_lng` to `number` or `float` currently all are string. [Comparison operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) worked on number